# Rails 4 and HTML5 exponential/list-of-values range field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there anyway to make a Rails 4 range_field with an exponential range field?

I would like to have a range field with, lets say, 5 values: 1 - 20 - 400 - 8000 - 160000. Is there a way to do this with the Range Field helper?

My range field is like this:

```
<%= f.range_field :range, in: 10..100 , step: 10 %>
```

But what I was trying to do would be something like:

```
<%= f.range_field :range, in: [1, 20, 400, 800, 16000] %>
```

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bootstrap slider that does exactly this and also has a gem for rais: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

Thanks!